# Cannot use parameter as an unsigned int with pass by reference C++

Tags: c++, arguments, parameter-passing, unsigned-integer

I have some C++ code:

```
#include <bjarne/std_lib_facilities.h>

double random(unsigned int &seed);
int main ()
{
    int seed = 42;
    cout << random((unsigned int)seed) << endl;
}

double random(unsigned int &seed)
{
    const int MODULUS = 15749;
    const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    seed = (( MULTIPLIER * seed) + INCREMENT) % MODULUS;
    return double (seed)/MODULUS;
}
```

I'm getting an error when I try to compile:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘unsigned int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘unsigned int’

cout << random((unsigned int)seed) << endl;
```

I don't understand why I can't use the `int seed` as a parameter for the function `random`. I even tried `type-casting` the int into an unsigned int for the parameter. I can't make the `unsigned int &seed` parameter a `const` variable because I'm changing its value within the function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After the cast, you don't have a lvalue anymore. You can't non const reference a casted value. Define an `unsigned int` variable in first place.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts, they are for legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an lvalue reference to a type, you can only initialize it with things of *that type*:

```
T obj = ...;
T& ref = obj;
```

or of a *derived type*:

```
Derived obj = ...;
Base& ref = obj;
```

That's it. You're trying to initialize an `unsigned int&` with an `int`. Or, with the cast, you're trying to initialize an lvalue reference with a temporary. Those don't fit either of the two allowable cases. You'll just have to pass in the correct type to begin with:

```
unsigned int seed = 42;
cout << random(seed);
```

Although, why does `random()` change the seed? Seems like you should be passing it in by value...